# Set statusbar -> black color

Tags: android, background, statusbar

I'm trying to set my app theme without actionbar (title) and with black statusbar, but I can't accomplish that. I went through old topics about this, but didn't find any solution. Any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mrti.menu">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting the color in your custom theme.  Starting in lollipop (and with AppCompat), the values correspond as shown in the image below:

[image: Theme]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest, set the theme to `AppTheme`.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

If you want to do it programmatically, try:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: Programmatical approach was the one, I was looking for. Thank you!